# How to register MFC ActiveX control?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, com, activex

I am working on an old MFC project, which tries to load some ActiveX control by GUID and fails because that GUID is not registered yet, and I can't register it.

The solution has several projects in it, generating DLLs and EXE:

```
Solution
- {name} project => {name}.exe
  - {control}.h and {control}.cpp for MFC control ({control} class). 
    It has `static CLSID const clsid` which is being initialized to GUID the app tries to use.
  - {name}.rc file which describes a lot of dialogs and other resources. 
    Some of dialogs reference that {control} by its GUID.

- {lib} project => {lib}.dll
  - {lib}.rc file which describes a lot of dialogs and other resources. 
    Some of dialogs reference {control} by its GUID.
```

How should I register the control so it could be loaded by its GUID? There are no .OCX, .TLB, .IDL files after build, and both `regsvr32 /i {name}.exe` and `regsvr32 /i {lib}.dll` fail to do anything.

Comment: [How to: Register Automation Servers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05c9yccf). Note that you need administrator's command prompt.

Comment: @RomanR. Thanks for the answer. It was not what had to be done, but it helped me to find the problem: InitInstance of CWinApp was overriden to try to register .OCX from another solution.